# Bokeh figure doesn't show

Tags: python-2.7, data-visualization, bokeh

I am new to python. I tried the example given in here http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/color_scatter.html with my own dataset, which looks like this

```
   Unnamed: 0  fans                      id  stars
0           0    69  18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyKyAZPw   4.14
1           1  1345  rpOyqD_893cqmDAtJLbdog   3.67
2           2   105  4U9kSBLuBDU391x6bxU-YA   3.68
3           3     2  fHtTaujcyKvXglE33Z5yIw   4.64
4           4     5  SIBCL7HBkrP4llolm4SC2A   3.80
```

here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
op = pd.read_csv('FansStars.csv')

x = op.stars
y = op.fans
radii = 1.5
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (int(r), int(g), 150) for r, g in zip(50+2*x, 30+2*y)]

TOOLS="hover,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select,"

p = figure(tools=TOOLS)

p.scatter(x, y, radius=radii,
      fill_color=colors, fill_alpha=0.6,
      line_color=None)

output_file("color_scatter.html", title="color_scatter.py example")

show(p)
```

However, when I run this code, I get no error and a webpage is opened, but BLANK. On reloading several times, I can finally see the tools, but that's all.
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any relevant output or log messages in your browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant replicate this on Python 3.4 with Bokeh 0.12.3. So in that way, your code seems fine. I tried it both in the notebook (output_notebook) and to a file like you do and both seem to work fine.

The radius of 1.5 which you specify is taken in data units (x apparently), this makes the circles extremely big, covering the entire screen at first render. But using the wheelzoom to zoom out a bit reveals all circles as expected. Here is what your code looks like in Firefox for me (after zooming out):

[image]

Comment: Can RAM be a problem? It doesn't render on my system with 6GB RAM

Comment: The entire output of `color_scatter.py` with 4000 circles is ~1Mb so that's highly unlikely unless your data set has billions of rows (in which case you need to look at something like [bokeh/datashader](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader))