# Holoview with bokeh does not show plots

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, data-visualization, interactive, holoviews

I'm trying to create an environment in which I develop Python code with PyCharm while at the same time creating interactive charts using holoviews and bokeh.

I followed steps in [Holoview Introduction](http://holoviews.org/getting_started/Introduction.htmlhttp://) and it works in Jupyter notebook - the charts are nicely interactive indeed. However, when I run the same code in PyCharm's Python Console, no charts or browser shows up.

In contrast, when I directly call bokeh's methods, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775559/bokeh-figure-doesnt-show), a browser launches and I can manipulate the charts interactively. I would like to achieve this using holoviews (+bokeh).

Many thanks for your help in advance.

My libraries:

- Python 3.4.5
- holoviews 1.8.1
- bokeh 0.12.6
- param 1.5.1
- ipython 6.1.0
- jupyter 1.0.0
- pandas 0.20.3
- numpy 1.13.1
- scipy 0.19.1

Answer (score 10):

**The only thing you need to add** to your code is `show(hv.render(your_holoviews_plot))`, like this:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.plotting import show

show(hv.render(your_holoviews_plot))
```

When you run your script in PyCharm (or any other IDE), this will open your plot in the browser.

It sets **bokeh as renderer** and **uses bokeh.plotting.show() to open the plot** in the browser.
So no need to go to the commandline etc.

**Full working example code:**

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv

# setting bokeh as backend
hv.extension('bokeh')

# going to use show() to open plot in browser
from bokeh.plotting import show

# create some sample data
data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data,
    columns=['col1', 'col2'],
)

# using hvplot here to create a holoviews plot
# could have also just used holoviews itself
plot = df.hvplot(kind='scatter', x='col1', y='col2')

# use show() from bokeh
show(hv.render(plot))
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is in:
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html

you need these lines of code:

```
import holoviews.plotting.bokeh
....
layout=#whathever holoview you want to plot
...
doc = hv.renderer('bokeh').server_doc(layout)
```

And then go to your command prompt, cd to the right directory and run: bokeh serve --show myscript.py

Comment: This example is even easier using panel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208035/why-doesnt-holoviews-show-histogram-in-spyder