# How do i get my interactive Holoviews graph to display in Visual Studio (without Jupyter)?

Tags: python, visual-studio, holoviews, holoviz, panel-pyviz

I'm mainly using Jupyter Notebook / Lab when using Holoviews for interactive plotting. 
How do I make Visual Studio display my interactive graphs and panels, without using the Interactive Jupyter inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Easiest solution** is to set bokeh as backend of the renderer and then **use bokeh.render.show()**. This will open your holoviews plot in the browser:

```
hv.extension('bokeh')
from bokeh.plotting import show

show(hv.render(your_holoviews_plot))
```

**Full working example:**

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv

# setting bokeh as backend
hv.extension('bokeh')

# going to use show() to open plot in browser
from bokeh.plotting import show

# create some sample data
data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data,
    columns=['col1', 'col2'],
)

# using hvplot here to create a holoviews plot
# could have also just used holoviews itself
plot = df.hvplot(kind='scatter', x='col1', y='col2')

# use show() from bokeh
show(hv.render(plot))
```

Comment: Note for future users: this creates a non-interactive holoviews plot, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57971108/1256347) creates an interactive holoviews plot (where you can zoom/pan).

Answer (score 4):

One way to use interactive graphs from Holoviews etc in Visual Studio is executing code to show the graph in your browser (which Holoviews is meant for).
**The example below puts your Holoviews graph in a Panel and starts a Bokeh server.**
**It opens a new tab on your browser and shows your graph.**

```
# library imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)
import panel as pn

# create sample data
data = np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

# create holoviews graph
hv_plot = hv.Points(df)

# display graph in browser
# a bokeh server is automatically started
bokeh_server = pn.Row(hv_plot).show(port=12345)

# stop the bokeh server (when needed)
bokeh_server.stop()
```

Comment: The `hv_plot` could also be created like in the another answer; with `hv_plot = df.hvplot(kind="scatter", x="col1", y="col2")`. Then, I believe importing `holoviews` is not needed. Not sure what `hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)` does, but I seem not need it (is it related to Jupyter notebooks?).

Comment: yeah, hv.extension() is not really necessary. And, since the question mentioned HoloViews instead of hvplot, I created a plot with holoviews instead of hvplot. But both would be fine here :)