# Use hvplot interactive to render loop in browser, and save as html

Tags: python, python-xarray, interactive, hvplot

I am trying to follow this [example notebook](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Interactive.html), specifically the plotting section where it plots the x,y grid and loops/scrolls through the time dimension.

```
ds.air.interactive.sel(time=pnw.DiscreteSlider).plot()
```

I'm running into two issues. The first is, I'd like to run this code in the Spyder IDE, which does not support the inline widgets. Based on a few other questions I've found here, the solution seems to be to have the interactive widget render in a browser window. I've looked around a few spots, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208035/why-doesnt-holoviews-show-histogram-in-spyder), but I can't seem to find anything that works with the `hvplot.xarray.XArrayInteractive` objects that are created here. So my first question is how to get these to render in a browser window.

My second question is how to save these loops as an html file that can be opened later. I've tried using the tutorial [here](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Viewing.html#saving-plots), but when I try to save it, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: HoloViews pane does not support objects of type 'XArrayInteractive'.
```

It seems like in both cases, using this "XArrayInteractive" type might be causing the issue. I am not locked into using this method, if there is another way to make the loops I want, I am open to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get this to work in Spyder. Here is a full code example from https://hvplot.holoviz.org/ showing the additional lines of code to get it to work in Spyder:

```
import hvplot.xarray
import panel as pn
import xarray as xr
hv.extension('bokeh')
da = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').air
w_quantile = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name='quantile', start=0, end=1)
w_time = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name='time', start=0, end=10)

app = da.interactive(loc='left') \
.isel(time=w_time) \
.quantile(q=w_quantile, dim='lon') \
.hvplot(ylabel='Air Temperature [K]', width=500)

app.layout().show(threaded=True) # displays the interactive dashboard
app.layout().save("dashboard.html", embed=True) # saves the html file
```

The last two lines are the secret. The interactive command returns an hvplot.xarray.XArrayInteractive object Which does not work with the methods described in the [first link you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208035/why-doesnt-holoviews-show-histogram-in-spyder). The app.layout() command returns a [panel object](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Dashboards.html); which you can use to plot in Spyder. There is more information in the last link about this.